# How to persist file uploads after validation error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a form that requires a file to be uploaded as well as additional data (name, etc...) with validation on these fields.  When an error occurs, the file has to be re-uploaded.  Is there a way to keep the file after a validation error occurs?  This is built in C# .NET.

Tried to google this but nothing helpful came up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post some code.  Not picturing how a validation error would delete the file?  And WPF or winforms

Comment: persists in the sense it should keep track of the URL from the disk ... ? I guess it's just a browser thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't genually persist the file because of Security Purpose..
If page is posted and validation error occured, check for a file using the .PostedFile property, and if one exists, save it to a temp file. In Session, store a reference to the temporary file. (use javascript)

.PostedFile is a property of the FileUpload control.

Also, during my google research, I found AJAX RadControl related to your question..

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-persist-uploaded-files.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a bit of a guess at what you're doing since you really can't persist a file... are you simply using a fileupload dialog box and taking it from there? If so, it's typical to put the file/path obtained from the dialog in a txt field, then do your post (upload) with a separate button.

This scenario assumes you want to persist the path/file name, but not the actual file.